# How to use functions in parameters as filters?

Tags: c#

I want to call this function from an interface.

```
ICollection<Store> GetStores(Func<Store, bool> filter, bool includeCustomers = false);
```

How would you call it? 
It takes a filtering function, which I don't know how to use.

```
var returnStores = IRepository.GetStores(/*what to write here*/);
```

For example to find a store with storeID:

```
public class Store
{
  public int StoreId { get; set; }
  public string CountryCode { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you should write lambda function with condition, e.g. `var returnStores = IRepository.GetStores(store => store.StoreId > 5);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass in the name of an existing method that matches the required signature: A method that receives a `Store` and returns a boolean.

Otherwise, you can pass an anonymous function like this:

```
var returnStores = IRepository.GetStores(store => store.Id == 42);
```

The anonymous function receives a `Store` and returns `true` only if its `Id` is 42. This is just an example, the point is that **the lambda must return a bool**.

Comment: Correction. The lambda doesn't return a `Store`, it returns a `bool`.

Comment: I am getting this error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property `

Comment: @AHAMES this fixes your issue in this post. You're having other issues that doesn't pertain to this post, please ask another question. Also without this invincible code, we can't tell you what's wrong

Answer (score 3):

A `Func<Store, bool>` is any function that receives a `Store` as input and returns a `bool` as output.

So, the ones that return `true` will be in the collection.

You can use a `lambda expression` for that:

```
var returnStores = IRepository.GetStores(store => store.StoreId == the_id_you_want);
```

For more complex funtions, you can use:

```
var returnStores = IRepository.GetStores(store => {
         blablabla(store);
         store.blablabla();
         blablabla;
         return a_boolean;
    });
```

Comment: I am getting this error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property `

Comment: @AHAMES that is completely unrelated with the present question. If you have another question, aks a new question including any relevant code.

Comment: @AHAMES, your error is "probably" because you are using `IRepository.GetStores`, while `IRepository` is not an instance, it's just the name of the interface. The error says the method you're using is an "instance" method (called from an instance), not a "static" method (called from the class name) --- But this is a guess.